# wamp server not working

Tags: wampserver

I've stopped IIS but still wamp is not working. In test 80 it's blank. What shall i do now?

Comment: But only with *way* more details, otherwise I'll feel bad to dump this on them. Please add some meaningful information and error messages when starting wamp

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ways to make wampserver work.

1. Check the icon of wampserver.

   - **RED** ===> Service not working.
   - **ORANGE** ===> Not working.
   - **GREEN** ===> I'm working!
2. Test if another service is using port 80 by clicking the `wampserver icon > Apache > Test Port 80`. It will open your command prompt and display whether or not any service is using **port 80**. Another way of doing it: click on the icon of window and search cmd then hit enter to type

   ```
   netstat -ano
   ```

   and check in the **PID column** if any service is using port 80. Most frequently it will be **Skype and IIS** that will use port 80.
3. If Skype is using port 80, simply open Skype, click on `tool > options > advanced > connections` and uncheck the box that says "*use port 80 and 443 as alternative*".
4. Once finished with the port 80, if it still doesn't work, click the icon of wampserver > apache > httpd.conf and change the following lines

   ```
   Listen 0.0.0.0:80
   Listen [::0]:80
   ```

   to this

   ```
   Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
   Listen [::0]:8080
   ```

   and this line

   ```
   ServerName localhost:80
   ```

   to this

   ```
   ServerName localhost:8080
   ```

   Save your file and type in your browser http://localhost:8080 and generally it should work.
5. The problem might also come when it says

   > VCRUNTIME.dll is missing

   or something like that. In this case, you are missing **Visual Studio 2012 VC 11 vcredist_x64/86.exe** (depending the version of wampserver you're using) when you should have read the warning sign before installing it. To fix it, go to http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679 or whichever version of it you need to use, and download it. Run the program and click on repair.
6. After all these steps, restart wampserver by clicking `wampserver icon > Restart all services` and refresh your localhost. If you changed to using port 8080, enter `:8080` just after entering localhost in your adress bar and this should work.

Hope this helped.